# Monacaからニフティクラウドを操作できない。

Tags: javascript, html, monaca

Monacaでスマホアプリを作っています。
初めにボタンをクリックしたら登録するコードを書き、そちらはうまく動きました。
しかし、次に作ったコードが動きません。
どうすればいいか教えてほしいです。
よろしくお願いします。

[作りたい動き]
1.絵文字を入力
2.ボタンをクリック
3.絵文字をunicodeにしてニフティクラウドに登録

[実際に起きてしまう動き]
エラーが発生する。
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '/classes/listEmoji')

[試してみたこと]
・コードの再確認
→おかしなところはなし。

・ニフティクラウドのテーブルの作り直し
→同じエラーが発生。

・コードを最低限にしてみる。
→同上

・もう一度ちゃんと動く方のコードを実行してみる。
→エラーなく動いた。

【index.html】

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
  <script src="js/ncmb.min.js"></script>
  <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
  <script src="components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  
    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <script>
    window.fn = {};
    window.fn.open = function() {
      var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
      menu.open();
    };
    
    window.fn.load = function(page) {
      var content = document.getElementById('content');
      var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
      content
        .load(page)
        .then(menu.close.bind(menu));
    };

    if (ons.platform.isIPhoneX()) {
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('onsflag-iphonex-portrait', '');
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('onsflag-iphonex-landscape', '');
    }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ons-splitter>
    <ons-splitter-side id="menu" side="left" width="220px" collapse swipeable>
      <ons-page>
        <ons-list>
          <!-- <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('home.html')" tappable> -->
          <ons-list-item onclick="onsenClick('home.html')" tappable>
            Home
          </ons-list-item>
         <!--  <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('settings.html')" tappable> -->
         <ons-list-item onclick="onsenClick('settings.html')" tappable>
            勤務形態登録    
          </ons-list-item>
          <!-- <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('about.html')" tappable> -->
          <ons-list-item onclick="onsenClick('about.html')" tappable>
            About
          </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
      </ons-page>
    </ons-splitter-side>
    <ons-splitter-content id="content" page="home.html"></ons-splitter-content>
  </ons-splitter>
  <template id="home.html">
    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-toolbar-button onclick="fn.open()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-ios-menu, material:md-menu"></ons-icon>
          </ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          Main
        </div>
      </ons-toolbar>    
      <p id="formEmoji">
        <p>【絵文字登録フォーム】</p>
        <label for="status0">仕事：</label><br>
        <input type="text" class="statusJob" id="status0"><br>
        <label for="status1">休み：</label><br>
        <input type="text" class="statusJob" id="status1"><br>
        <label for="status2">テレワーク：</label><br>
        <input type="text" class="statusJob" id="status2"><br>
        <label for="statusother">その他：</label>
        <input type="text" id="statusother"><br>
        <input type="text" class="statusJob" id="status3"><br>
        <p><button id="emojiTouroku" type="button" onclick="test()">登録</button></p>
      </p>
    </ons-page>
  </template>
  <template id="settings.html">
  <ons-page>
    <!-- ここは二ページ目 -->    
  </ons-page>
  </template>

  <template id="about.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button onclick="fn.open()">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-ios-menu, material:md-menu"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        About
      </div>
    </ons-toolbar>
  </ons-page>
  </template>
</body>
</html>
```

【index.js】

```
var hiduke = new Date();
var next_hiduke = new Date();
var txt_calendar = "";
var y = new Date().getFullYear();
var m = new Date().getMonth();
var sts = true;
var stsToday = false;
var toggleButton = document.querySelector(".toggle-button-list");
var week_text = ("日","月","火","水","木","金","土");
var ncmb = new NCMB("api_key","cli_key");
        

document.addEventListener("init", function(){
    /*
        ここにうまく動く登録コードなどあり
    */
});

function test() {
  var listEmoji = new ncmb.DataStore('listEmoji');
  console.log("Start!");
  
  console.log('データが正常に保存されました。');
}
```

【ニフティクラウドの画面】
赤で囲まれているのが対象テーブルです。
[image: ここに説明]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

理由はわかりませんが解決したので閉じます。
色々ありがとうございました。